# Disassembly debugging won't find my address

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, assembly, disassembly

I'm having an issue where I try and debug my application in Visual Studio 2012.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to search for an address in the top address bar. I insert my address, for example, 00C44873, press enter and it errors back:

> The specified address cannot be displayed. invalid octal digit.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to append an "h" to your hexadecimal number, like in assembly. 
For example, `00C44873h`. This now allows Visual Studio 2012 to search for this address.

Comment: This works! It must be documented somewhere but I can’t find it!